# How to fix when callback url has word 'GRANT' which is security violation in Coldfusion

Tags: security, coldfusion, access-violation

In coldfusion 11, I got an unexpected issue when callback url is below from Azure AD SSO

http://xxx123.net?displayName=**Grant**%2C%20Good&givenName=Good&id=xxxxxxxxxx&jobTitle=Stackoverflow&mail=Good.**Grant**%40xxx.com&&surname=**Grant**

then show error.

```
GRANT: Security violation, broken link, SQL reserved word or APP problem - We have detected a problem in APP, which can either be the use of illegal content in the URL, a APP application problem, missing data, a broken link or the use of an SQL reserved word (e.g. SELECT, DELETE, OUTER). Application execution has been halted. If you can reproduce this problem, please inform the system administrators. We will look into the problem as soon as possible. Thank you.
```

The root cause : **'Grant'** is security violation of URL.

I tried use rant instead of grant as the link below, and that's working.

http://xxx123.net?displayName=**rant**%2C%20Good&givenName=Good&id=xxxxxxxxxx&jobTitle=Stackoverflow&mail=Good.**rant**%40xxx.com&&surname=**rant**

Although, I tried using Grant1 or GrantX or 1Grant. Also does not work fine.

So, how to resolve this problem to avoid a problem above ?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what xxx123.net is doing with those variables.

Comment: Are you properly parameterizing these URL variables? As passed, "Grant" is nothing more than a string, but apparently it is trying to do some other processing of the values of your URL variables.

Comment: Something is catching a potential SQL Injection attack. Is this error coming from your application code, web application firewall, the SSO provider or elsewhere? Can't determine how to solve this until we know what is catching the error. Could you `POST` this data as form parameters instead of passing the values in the querystring? You probably don't want that data in the querystring anyway, that can be recoded in logs and raises another potential security issue.